# Setting pointer to NULL after free in quirky data structures (C)

Tags: c, pointers, null, valgrind, free

I have the following following somewhat convoluted data structures: a binary tree made up of nodes, and a linked list of items, each item storing tree nodes. If a `Node` is created, then it will certainly be used in a `Tree`, in a `List`, or both. Here are the data structures:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Item Item;

struct Node {
    int key;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

typedef struct {
    Node *root;
} Tree;

struct Item {
    Node *value;
    Item *next;
};

typedef struct {
    Item *head;
} List;
```

I am having trouble free'ing my tree and list. Logically, I would first free the `Tree`, and then the `List`. My idea was to set the `Node` pointers to `NULL` after freeing them in order for the `List` to decide whether the current `Item` has non-`NULL` nodes which must be free'd.

Here is how the `Tree` is free'd:

```
void tree_free_helper(Node *node)
{
    if (node) {
        tree_free_helper(node->left);
        tree_free_helper(node->right);
        free(node);
        node = NULL;
    }
}

void tree_free(Tree *tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        tree_free_helper(tree->root);
        free(tree);
    }    
}
```

This works fine if `Node`s only belong to a `Tree`. However, when a `Node` is also stored in a `List` `Item`, I get one extra `free` call = number of `malloc`s + 1. Here is how I free a `List`:

```
void list_free(List *list)
{
    Item *p, *q;

    if (!list) return;

    p = list->head;
    while (p) {
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
        if (q->value) // trying to free only non-free'd nodes
            free(q->value);
        free(q);
    }

    free(list);
}
```

Valgrind dutifully informs me that `Address 0x52040e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd`, and where in my code the block 0x52040e0 `was alloc'd at`. Here's a simple example for which I get this valgrind report, where I create 3 nodes for a `Tree` (`n1` being the root and having `n0` as left child and `n2` as right child); the problem comes from appending one of the nodes (`n0` in this example) to a `List`:

```
int main() {
    List *list = list_create();
    Tree *tree = tree_create();

    Node *n0 = node_create(0);
    Node *n1 = node_create(1);
    Node *n2 = node_create(2);

    tree->root = n1;
    n1->left = n0;
    n1->right = n2;

    list_append(list, n0);

    tree_free(tree);
    list_free(list);
}
```

Note: `list_create`, `tree_create`, and `node_create` respectively create a `List`, a `Tree`, and a `Node`. `list_append` creates an `Item` that is added to the list, and the item stores the `Node` passed as argument.

So my question is: seeing that setting the node pointer to `NULL` after I free it does not seem to have any effect, as `if (q->value)` always evaluates to true in `list_free`, what am I doing wrong? Thank you for any insight.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check for `NULL` in your `free()` function if you ignore that allocation might actually produce a `NULL`.

Comment: Pardon if this detail was buried somewhere in there (I couldn't find it). Are the *same* nodes pointed to by *both* structures? By the looks of the code in `main`, it seems so. If so, you need to decide which "owns" them (the tree or the list). The one that doesn't shouldn't be freeing their `node`, but should still be removing their `List` (or `Tree`) matching the corresponding `Node` from their respective formal structures.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I _do_ check for the return value of `malloc` in my `..._create` functions. The check for `NULL` in `list_free` is meant to check whether the current item in the list still contains a valid reference to a node, and in this case free the node (i.e. the node was never in the tree).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, indeed, _some_ nodes are pointed to by both structures. I decided on the Tree owning the Nodes, in which case the List only removes (frees) Nodes that do not belong to the Tree. It is a bit convoluted, I know.

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting the pointer to `NULL` really,

```
void tree_free_helper(Node *node)
{
    if (node) {
        tree_free_helper(node->left);
        tree_free_helper(node->right);
        free(node);
        node = NULL;
    }
}
```

only sets the local `node` pointer to `NULL`, you would need something like the following

```
void tree_free_helper(Node **node)
{
    if (node && *node) {
        tree_free_helper(&(*node)->left);
        tree_free_helper(&(*node)->right);
        free(*node);
        *node = NULL;
    }
}
```

Pointer variables and parameters just like any other variables and parameters are allocated in the stack frame of the function so they have a life time equal to that of the function, so when you set `node` to `NULL` you are actually only setting the variable `node` to `NULL` and not the pointer itself.

If you want to set the pointer, you have to pass it's address — *or a pointer to the pointer* — instead to be able to modify it inside the function.

Comment: `if (node)` should probably be `if (node && *node )` in your code.

Comment: Oh! I understand! Thanks for pointing this out, now it makes sense come to think of it. I am now calling `tree_free_helper` from `tree_free` like this: `tree_free_helper(&(tree->root));`. Unfortunately, valgrind still shows me 7 allocs and 8 frees with the same culprit (the node being appended to the list).

Comment: If you call valgrind with the right switches it will tell you where the alloc was. And that way you can track the leak. Also compile with debug symbols.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi It isn't a leak; it's a double-free (seven allocs, eight frees), likely because of the reason I commented on below the OP post.

Comment: I'm using it with `--leak-check=full` (not sure if this is what you had in mind). I'll get into it and come back here when (if?) I manage to solve the problem.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi While I understand your answer and it seems the right way to do it, even using a pointer to pointer as you suggested does not solve the double free problem: `if (q->value)` still evaluates to true in `list_free`. The dirty workaround I resorted to in order to avoid double free errors is to check before free'ing nodes in the tree whether they are also stored by items of the list. If this is the case, the pointer to the node in the list item is set to NULL before free'ing the node. Sorry for not accepting your answer (+1!), but it does not solve the problem yet.